# select most recent message grouped by foreign key in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Working on a rails app. My Message Table looks like this:

### Message Table

recipient_id | engagement_id

My goal is to show the most recent message of an engagement, with the same recipient_id as the current_user, grouped by engagement.
This post seems like what I am going for

[Finding the most recent entry per reference (foreign key) in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229662/finding-the-most-recent-entry-per-reference-foreign-key-in-rails)

Having trouble getting my syntax correct.
Here's where I have currently:

select message,MAX(time) as MaxTime from Message Group by engagement_id

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just realized select is html and I was looking for a rails function

Comment: So I went another route by adding some columns to my models. I'm still curious if there is a way to do this as described above, in case anyone has some thoughts.